# Button Image sizes?

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android soundboard application that uses many different buttons, and I have ran into a bit of a predicament, all the pictures for the imagebuttons that I have used have all ready been resized to 61 by 57 px and stored in the drawable folder, but now I need to make separate drawable folders for each pixel density category drawable-ldpi,drawable-mdpi etc., so how would I resize each picture for each folder, from the original 61 by 57.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Do you have the pictures before they got resized? In their original ratio?

Comment: No sadly I do not, and I resized them originally for the purpose of fitting onto the screen I was working on without realizing that, I would later on need to adapt them to work on a wide variety of devices. So is there any way I can make them the right format for my different pixel density folders.@Vucko

Comment: I don't know what code I should post its more of a question of what I should resize the pictures to, for each folder(from the original 61X57).@ing0